# SSRS express 2017, Configuration manager does not connect to service; RPC issue

Tags: reporting-services, rpc, ssrs-2017

I just upgraded SSRS Express 2016 to SSRS Express 2017.

When configuring the service I can set the web service url and the Web Portal url.

When creating a new database I can use the wizard without any issue. Database credentials are ok, connection test are successful and so on.

However, when it is time to make the creation effective, the last step of the wizard, there is an error when "Generating database script".

Here are the details:

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: An error occurred when attempting to connect to the report server remote procedure call (RPC) end point. Verify that the Report Server Windows service is running, and then retry the operation.
>
> ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The RPC server is not listening. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706B3)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.ThrowOnError(ManagementBaseObject mo)
>   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.GenerateDatabaseScript(String databaseName, Int32 lcid, Boolean isSharePointIntegrated, String& script)
>   at ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.RSReportServerAdmin.GenerateDatabaseScript(String databaseName, Int32 lcid, Boolean isSharePointIntegrated, String& script)

The only clue it gives it to make sure the service is running. I confirm the service is really running. What do I don't understand?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same issue a few days ago. I solved it by adding local admin rights to the service account that I have, that runs the SSRS instance. I guess it needs more than normal user rights to start the WMIProvider.